# recording timestamps of audio samples while recording using a java applicatin

Tags: java, audio, timestamp, audio-recording, javasound

I've made a java audio recorder and would like to know the system timestamp of each audio sample that I record.  I am recording for 1sec at 44.1KHz.  For each sample (theres 441000) I would like to record the time (system timestamp) that the microphone detected the sound.  How would I do this, if it is possible?  I would like an accuracy of +-1ms.

this is a snap shot of the code im using.

```
AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(44100f, 8, 1, true, false);
DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
TargetDataLine line = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
line.open(format);
line.start();
byte[] buff = new byte[line.getBufferSize()];
while(recording){
    int index = line.read(buff, 0, buff.length);
    out.write(buff, 0, index);
}
line.stop();
line.close();
byte[] audio = out.toByteArray();
```

Thanks

Edit

Getting a timestamp ever other sample, or even every 10 samples would be ok as long as its accurate.  Also i meant 44100* samples.

Comment: *" How would I do this, if it is possible?"*  There is no facility to store that information in the recording.  So to where exactly are you intending to record it, and how are you intending to associate that 'time stamp file' with the Wav?  Personally I'd append the time of 'start of recording' in the file name produced for the sample.  Then simply calculate the time at any point beyond that, based on the playback position in the sample.

Comment: Im not saving it to any file. I just want to store the sound in byte[] and then determine the frequency.  Ultimately what I want to do is detect a particular frequency and be able to determine the time that I detected it. I was thinking of recording the system time as soon as i started to record, but it would've been best if i could record the timestamp of each individual sample. The reason that Im shying away from just saving the timestamp when i start to record is that I need to be able to determine the EXACT time that I start to record. Im not sure how to do that wt an error less than .5ms

Comment: This is because I have several other threads running concurrently

Answer (score 1):

Actually, recording the start time is the simplest answer. You can always determine the start and stop time of any sound with incredible accuracy (per frame!) by using the frame count. At 44100 frames per second, if your analysis shows that pitch A starts at frame 22050 and ends 33075 for example, then you know that the sound went from exactly (start + 500) milliseconds to (start + 750) milliseconds. It's just a simple multiply operation.

Are you using some sort of Fast Fourier analysis to get the pitches?

It is possible to tie event-notification to Lines. Check out LineEvent and LineListener, in javax.sound.sampled api.

By the way, using frame count is possibly more accurate than time-stamping, due to vagaries introduced by JVM time-slicing. Java gives continuous/accurate playback of sound a high priority, but few real-time guarantees otherwise.